# Setting different color for each line in multiline TEXTBOX

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, textbox

My Code:

```
For Each dr In dt.Rows()
  If (cnt = 0) Then
     tx_control2.Text = dr("Name").ToString.Trim
  Else
     tx_control2.Text = tx_control2.Text + Environment.NewLine + dr("Name").ToString.Trim
  End If
  cnt = cnt + 1

Next ' for row
```

Using above code to add all names from datatable to TEXTBOX using Environment.NewLine.
This is adding all names in TEXTBOX.Now **I want different color for alternate names.**

I used :

```
tx_control2.ForeColor = Color.Maroon
```

But above solution change the color of all names.

I looking for solution.

Thanks.

Comment: All of the text in a `TextBox` control is displayed in the same color. If you need rich formatting with multiple colors, you need to use the appropriately named `RichTextBox` control, instead. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399208/vb-net-multicolor-richtextbox) for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with a TextBox. You'll have to use a RichTextBox for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rich text box instead, normal text boxes don't provide the kind of control you need.