# How to change the font of a TextBox

Tags: c#, fonts

I have a `Textbox` and a `Button`.
what I want is when I press the button `textbox1.Text` should change it's font style.

How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people can show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask] also..

Comment: take a look this link:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/696f80d0-8799-404e-9933-90991c697708/

Comment: learning "How to google the things" is more important for you than c#

Comment: I can't finde the exacly answer to my question. So, I hoped You guys could help me. But No you can't! thanks anyway...

Comment: What you want is having more that one font in the same textbox. Use `RichTextBox` and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399208/vb-net-multicolor-richtextbox

Answer (score 2):

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

**Refer:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/696f80d0-8799-404e-9933-90991c697708/

Answer (score 2):

your button_click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Font myfont = new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f); 
   Textbox1.Font = myfont;
}
```

Comment: thanks!, but it is only one font. I want to have more than one. how do I do that?

Comment: One Font for One textbox .. what the other fonts for ?

Comment: how can I get fonts automaticly? can c# do that?

Comment: get automatically from where ? .. from textbox or from windows font collection ?

Comment: from windows font collection

Comment: @user1756081 : You read in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yf5t4e8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```