# how to change textbox/combobox font in runtime using c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the textbox and combobox font at runtime by using this code

```
combobox1.Font = new Font("Tamil", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
```

With this code, only fontstyle is changing into bold and font size is changed into 12, but there is no change in font(language "Tamil" ).

If I change the font in property, it means it works but in runtime it's not changing.

Is there is any mistake in my coding or any other ways to change the font in runtime?

**Solution**

I've found out that it is typo. Below is my current code.
the reason for problem is spelling mistake in font

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("senthamil"); 
Font font = new Font( fontFamily, 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); 
cmb_Product_Code.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("senthamil", 12F,System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Comment: i think the format is incorrect. try something like this. `comboBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tamil", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)))`

Comment: thank u for reply sir..this also not works sir...the same is result coming only change in font style & size but it's not make change in font

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vb.net - Multicolor RichTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399208/vb-net-multicolor-richtextbox)

Comment: @Sivashankar are you sure you have that font style? go to `Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Fonts` to check if `Tamil` font is installed.

Comment: Have you installed 'Tamil' font? Because thats not present by default

Comment: s sir..if i change this font in combobox property means it works.

Comment: @Sivashankar i've tried it to replicate this and I've no problem changing the font.

Comment: thank you thank you all for all replies i got the result ..there is some spelling mistake in my font ..now i got the result thank u very much for all your replies..  my code is FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("senthamil");
            Font font = new Font(
               fontFamily,
               16,
               FontStyle.Regular,
               GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            cmb_Product_Code.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("senthamil", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

Comment: @Sivashankar i think your code should work with only the final line. have you try removing the first two line to check if it works?

Comment: s it also works by using final 2 lines.. cmb_Product_Code.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("senthamil", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));  thanks for your reply

Comment: I doubt this will work on every client machine without that font installed @Sivashankar

Comment: @active92 if the font is not installed means it shows the error like font not found by using this code  FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("senthamil"); Font font = new Font( fontFamily, 16, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel); but my using this code cmb_Product_Code.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("senthamil", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0))); it wont shows the error it skips this is the only difference between two type of code

Comment: @JonesJoseph No its not working in client machine without installation of font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the font family to set the font and then use the font family in the font constructor. Check the msdn link below for syntax
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kxs7tfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank u for your reply i got the result ..there is some spelling mistake in my font name so it does not works ..thank u for your reply

Comment: @Sivashankar what was the correct spelling? Spelling of `Tamil` that you have mentioned in your post seems alright. Does it have anything to do with casing of how write it e.g. `Tamil` vs `tamil`?

Comment: @RBT there is no problem in letters .its not a case sensitive ..the correct font name is "senthamil" but in my previous coding i mentioned only "tamil" that's a problem

Comment: ohh! Glad to know that.